# Unary negation of unsigned integer

Tags: c#, c

I'm looking to convert this line of C code to C#:

```
const u64 a = 1, b = -a;
```

So my understanding is that both constants are unsigned 64-bit integers. If so, what is the result going to look like?

Or is the second constant actually promoted and therefore defined as a signed integer?

Comment: Are you asking what the result of running this will be in C, or what the equivalent C# should be?

Comment: Why do you want to negate an unsigned int? Doesn't that defeat the purpose?

Comment: @Chris: I'm asking both.

Comment: @jb: This is a line of code from somebody else's C program - I'm looking to convert the line to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the [behaviour of negating unsigned integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026694/c-unary-minus-operator-behavior-with-unsigned-operands), the representation of `-(u64)1` is all 1s. So, after the following:

```
const u64 a = 1, b = -a;

// a is now 0x0000000000000001
// b is now 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Of course, `0xffffffffffffffff` is also `(2^64) -1`, which is 18446744073709551615.

In my opinion, it would have been clearer for the original programmer to instead write:

```
const u64 a = 1, b = ~(u64)0;
```

I'm not a C# programmer, but I suspect the following will work for you:

```
const ulong b = ~(ulong)0;
```

Comment: I think `~0` depends on the same undefined behavior as `-1` (casting `int` to `uint64`). `~(u64)0` should solve this.

Comment: It's not UD in C. The standard clearly defines the result of conversion of signed negative integers to unsigned integers. But we don't even have that here. `1` is signed positive that is converted to unsigned (to type of `a`) without change. `a` is unsigned because it's defined as unsigned. And so is `-a`. See [this question and answers to it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8026694/968261)

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I'll remove the answer shortly. Can you tell me where the C standard defines the result of conversion from signed negative to unsigned? If I'm reading it correctly, in your question you say it doesn't?

Comment: @Alex: Updated answer to remove the comments about UB. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 4):

This would be the equivalent C#:

```
const ulong a = 1, b = unchecked((ulong)-1);
```

Or more simply:

```
const ulong a = 1, b = 18446744073709551615;
```

Comment: Aha - many thanks! So the C code actually results in an overflow to (in C#) UInt64.MaxValue?

Comment: If you want the max value `const ulong b = ~(ulong)0;` also works

Comment: @RoadWarrior - the result isn't due to an overflow, just the conversion to an unsigned 64 bit int. See my answer for details.

Comment: @TimothyJones: The value already has type `u64` when the negation operator is applied, so the huge value is due to reduction of arithmetic results modulo 2^64, not anything about conversion.

Answer (score 3):

The C# compiler will try to protect you from accidentally negiting an unsigned integer, but you can force it like this:

```
ulong a = 1;
ulong b = (ulong)-(long)a;
```

The result will be exactly the same bunch of bits as when negating a signed integer (i.e. two's complement), the only difference is how these bits are *interpreted*.

Comment: Thanks, that answers another question I had.

Answer (score 0):

You get an ambiguous invocation error because -1 is not possible as an unsigned type (see comment below). You would have to use Int64 as type (which equals long).

When using long as type then the result will be a = 1, b = -1 and both longs.

Comment: How can b be -1 if it's unsigned? Sorry, can't check at home as I only have the C# version of Visual Studio Express.

Comment: If that's about C, there's no error here, even though mathematically -1 cannot be non-negative. The only error can be that the programmer doesn't know what's he doing.