# Modulus Operator vs Zero (re: arc4random_uniform source)

Tags: c, math, cryptography, openbsd, type-bounds

Found myself looking at the arc4random_uniform source (http://bxr.su/o/lib/libc/crypt/arc4random_uniform.c)

My question relates to the following line (the comment is their original comment) :

```
/* 2**32 % x == (2**32 - x) % x */
min = -upper_bound % upper_bound;
```

Now, I'm no mathematics genius, but surely  -N%N will always equal zero.  So why not just write

```
min=0
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026694/c-unary-minus-operator-behavior-with-unsigned-operands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to note that we're dealing with unsigned ints (`uint32_t`) here, so `-upper_bound` doesn't do what you think it does. It's actually `2**32 - upper_bound`, due to modulo wrap-around, and the purpose of this is explained in the comment above (i.e. obtaining `2**32 % upper_bound` without overflow).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t upper_bound = 42;
    uint32_t min = -upper_bound % upper_bound;
    printf("%u -> %u\n", upper_bound, min);
    return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
42 -> 4
```

<kbd>[LIVE CODE](http://codepad.org/Qon9ZaLC)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

First it's worth mentioning that the variables are `uint32_t`, thus unsigned. Then lets look closely:
`-upper_bound % upper_bound = (-upper_bound) % upper_bound;`. It means that `-upper_bound` is actually 2's complement of `upper_bound`. Assume that `upper_bound=10`, then `-upper_bound` is `0xFFFFFFF6=246`. Then `-upper_bound % upper_bound = 246%10 = 6`. And you can test it.