# Char substraction with clipped underflow

Tags: c++, c, binary-operators

is there a way to compute:

```
/** clipped(a - b) **/
unsigned char clipped_substract(unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
{
    return a > b ? a - b : 0;
}
```

using some binary operations instead of a test?

Comment: No there is no such thing. What's wrong with your function?

Comment: If you use a cpu architecture that supports the mmx command extension set, you can perform an unsigned saturated subtraction to achieve this. Other architectures might have similar instructions.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I would like to optimize computation and tests can lower performances.

Comment: @Abitbol If you care about performance, you profile. You don't go by "tests can lower performance so I won't use tests". That's wrong, dangerous and will lead to bad code with bad performance. Again, profile or don't say you care about performance.

Comment: You should probably take a look at the generated code. If you're using a decent compiler, this code is simple enough for it to get optimized quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/** clipped(a - b) **/
unsigned char clipped_substract(unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
{
    return a - (a+b) / 2 + getAbs(a-b) / 2;
}

unsigned int getAbs(int n)
{
    int const mask = n >> (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1);

    return ((n + mask) ^ mask);
}
```

Comment: Is this really better? `abs` is likely to have a test, in that case this is less performant.

Comment: @Abitbol `abs` is easily implemented as clearing the sign bit of the integer. See https://godbolt.org/z/Qkb6Fk (here it uses sign extension instead of having the sign bit mask constant in the code).

Comment: `abs` *can* be calculated [without branching](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs). More efficient??? Won't be going to analyse...

Comment: It's not abs() that is the problem. This code has more operations than the single subtraction and is bound to be less performant than the original code. We should also remember that all modern processors have branch predictors.

Comment: @Abitbol I updated the answer with replacing the abs function.

Comment: True that I can't be asking for more efficient without going to analyse, I am just asking for an alternative candidate.

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, is a similar trick with addition overflow?

Comment: @Abitbol `a + b = a - (-b)` – obviously, you'd then just have to swap `+b` and `-b` in above algorithm...

Comment: @Aconcagua I would be very careful with unary minus on `unsigned`...

Comment: @MaxLanghof [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026694/c-unary-minus-operator-behavior-with-unsigned-operands)

Comment: I don't think this is any better: Look at the [generated assembly code](https://www.godbolt.org/z/TkEpoH). This version uses more than twice the number of instructions than the original version. I know the number of instructions is not the only thing that counts, but in this case I thnink it's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 8):

The original function compiles to a conditional move and is not subject to the performance concern you have. You are attempting to perform [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) here, and it will do absolutely no good for you. Write readable code, then profile it, then identify and optimize performance bottlenecks.

You say "tests can lower performances". If you want to do micro-optimizations like this, you should aim to understand the reasons underlying these rules of thumb, not apply them as unconditional truth.

What lowers performance about "tests" are (mispredicted) control flow branches. Modern CPUs heavily use [instruction pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining), and control flow branches mean it's unclear which instruction comes next. The common approach is that the CPU guesses (using branch prediction hardware/algorithms) which way the branch will go. If it gets it wrong, it has to flush the entire pipeline and refill it, which wastes cycles.

Well, the code in question has no such issue. It compiles to a conditional move:

https://godbolt.org/z/upkgok

```
clipped_substract(unsigned char, unsigned char):
    mov     eax, edi
    mov     edx, 0
    sub     eax, esi
    cmp     dil, sil
    cmovbe  eax, edx
    ret
```

You can see that there is no control flow branch here. See [Why is a conditional move not vulnerable for Branch Prediction Failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131096/why-is-a-conditional-move-not-vulnerable-for-branch-prediction-failure) for why that is not subject to the above performance concern.

I repeat: **Write readable code, then profile it, then identify and optimize performance bottlenecks.** What you attempted here was to fix a performance problem code that *didn't even exist in the first place* (not to mention you didn't prove that the performance of this code is even relevant to your program's performance).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! That's the best way to address the problem, but please excuse my curiosity.

Comment: Once it's started, I can't stop it hahaha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `clang 11.0`, compiler optimizations enabled

```
unsigned char clipped_substract(unsigned char a, unsigned char b)
{   
    long c = b - a;
    return ((unsigned long)c >> (sizeof(c)*8-1)) * c;
}
```

Although time taken by any of the alternatives is neglagibly different, but when performing `10000000` iterations, other ways take around `0.300secs` on my machine and this solution takes around `0.200secs`.

But this is only valid if you use a type whose size is greater than `char`, for example here I took `long`. I don't remember exact definitions of `char` or `long` but I know `long` is wider on my machine compared to `char`. So adjust it accordingly.

Basically, I just store the result of subtraction in a larger width variable. If the result is negative, most significant bit will be `1` else `0`.

Comment: No, never bit shift negative types. Needed bug fix: `((unsigned long)c >> (sizeof(c)*8-1)) * c;`. Otherwise you can't know if you get arithmetic or logical shift.

Comment: @Lundin Actually shifting negative types can be quite useful if there's a need to retain sign bit. As there's indeed no guarantee for arithmetic shift, I usually protect with `#if -1 >> 1 != -1 #error no arithmetic shift #endif` or similar...

Comment: @Aconcagua: this preprocessor test is not sufficient as the preprocessor may use different arithmetic than the target system.