# What function does the minus sign (-) operator have on a pointer variable in C?

Tags: c, operators

I encountered this line of code:

```
    memset(tmp, 0, (-len) & 0x7F);
```

Where `len` is a `uint8_t` **pointer** variable.

What's is the "**-**" doing to `len` before the bitwise operation? What would be the result?

Given it is an unsigned integer, I don't think it'd make sense to add a sign this way (if it is at all possible in C), even less with it being a pointer.

Comment: Please provide the full context of the code. That is, give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The `uint8_t` type is not a pointer type. If your `len` is actually a `uint8_t*` pointer, then your code won't compile.

Comment: @Santiago Marruffo len is not a pointer. You may not apply the unary operator - to pointers.

Comment: You need to provide more context and correct the error about `len` being any kind of pointer, but, for an unsigned integer type or a two’s complement type, `-len & 0x7F` evaluates to the smallest number of bytes `x` such that `len+x` is a multiple of 128. E.g., for `len` = 0, 128, or 256, `-len & 0x7F` is zero. For `len` = 1, 129, or 257, it is 127. For `len` = 2, it is 126. For `len` = 127, it is 1. This calculation is sometimes used to calculate how much padding is needed to fill out space up to a multiple of a number.

Comment: `uint8_t *len = ...; memset(tmp, 0, (-len) & 0x7F);` --> "error: wrong type argument to unary minus"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`len` cannot be a *pointer* to a variable, because the unary minus operator cannot accept a pointer as an operand. The code would not compile.
Considering the [function prototype of memset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset), it is more likely that `len` is of the type `uint8_t` here.
The behavior of applying the unary minus operator on unsigned types is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026694/c-unary-minus-operator-behavior-with-unsigned-operands).